# Make object traits inheritable

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a natural selection simulator program. One of the things I want to happen is when two parent objects collide for an offspring object to be created that randomly inherits some of its parents traits. In particular, I'm looking to pass on the int values width and height. The problem is, I'm only looking to pass on width and height into the object when it is offspring. I want the initial spawn of parent objects to have completely randomized values.

My whole code is:

```
import pygame, random

pygame.init()

map_width = 800
map_height = 800
size = [map_width, map_height]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# pygame already defines a lot of colors, we we just use them
colors = pygame.color.THECOLORS
pygame.display.set_caption("Natural Selection Game")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# just a simple generator to generate an id for each object 
def id_generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i

ids = id_generator()

# just a helper function that wraps pygame.sprite.collide_mask
# to prevent a sprite from colliding with itself
def collide(a, b):
    if a.id == b.id:
        return False
    return pygame.sprite.collide_mask(a, b)

class Organism(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, id, org_list, width, height, color = None):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, org_list)
        self.org_list = org_list
        self.id = id
        # Speed and direction
        self.change_x = random.randrange(0,6)
        self.change_y = random.randrange(0,6)

        # Dimensions
        self.width = width or random.randrange(20,60)
        self.height = height or random.randrange(20,60)

        x = random.randrange(0 + width, map_width - width )
        y = random.randrange(0 + height, map_height - height)
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(colors['hotpink2'])
        self.image.set_colorkey(colors['hotpink2'])

        # we either pass in the color, or create a random one
        self.color = color or random.choice([colors['red'], colors['green'], colors['blue']])
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, self.color, [0, 0, width, height])
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

        # we keep track of collisions currently happening
        # so we only spawn one children for each collisions  
        self.collisions = set()

        # just something to limit the number of organisms
        self.age = 0
        self.children = 0

    # Initiate movement
    def update(self):
        self.age += 1

        # we move by simply moving the rect
        # the Group's draw function will look that the rect attribute 
        # to determine the position for drawing the image 
        self.rect.move_ip(self.change_x, self.change_y)

        # we can make use of a lot of Rect's attributes to make 
        # this computation simpler
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > map_width:
            self.change_x *= -1

        if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > map_height:
            self.change_y *= -1

        # only reproduce if we are at least 200 ticks old
        # so newly created organisms spwan new ones at the
        # very moment they spawned themself
        if self.age < 200:
            return

        # just an arbitary limit so the screen does not get too full
        if self.age > 500:
            print (self.id, ' died of age')

            # kill() removes the Sprite from all its Groups (which is only org_list at the moment)
            self.kill()
            return

        # just an arbitary limit so the screen does not get too full 
        if self.children > 4:
            print (self.id, ' died of too many children')
            self.kill()
            return

        # check if we collided with another Sprite
        collided = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.org_list, collide)

        # also check if this 
        # - is a new collision
        # - the other organism is at least 200 ticks old
        # - there are not too many organisms at the screen at the moment
        if collided and not collided.id in self.collisions and collided.age > 200 and len(self.org_list) < 100:

            # keep track of the current collision, so this code is not triggerd 
            # every frame while the colliding organisms move other each other
            self.collisions.add(collided.id)
            collided.collisions.add(self.id)
            print (self.id, ' collided with ', collided.id)

            # inherit parent dimensions
            width = random.choice(self.width, collided.width)
            height = random.choice(self.height, collided.height)

            # let the dimensions mutate sometimes for fun
            if random.randrange(0, 100) < 5:
                width = random.randrange(5, 100)
                print ('Offspring of', self.id, ' and ', collided.id, ' mutates a dimension change')
            elif random.randrange(0, 100) < 5:
                height = random.randrange(5, 100)    
                print ('Offspring of', self.id, ' and ', collided.id, ' mutates a dimension change')
            elif random.randrange(0, 100) < 5:
                width = random.randrange(5, 100)
                height = random.randrange(5, 100)  
                print ('Offspring of', self.id, ' and ', collided.id, ' mutates a dimension change')

            # let the color mutate sometimes for fun
            if random.randrange(0, 100) < 5:
                color[random.randrange(0, 3)] = random.randrange(0, 256)
                print ('Offspring of', self.id, ' and ', collided.id, ' speciates')

            # create the new child with the new color
            Organism(next(ids), self.org_list, list(map(int, color)))
            self.children += 1
            collided.children += 1
        else:
            # if there are currently no collisions, we clear the collisions set
            # so new collisions can happen
            self.collisions = set()

# we use a Group for all the draw/update/collision magic
org_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

for _ in range(15):
    Organism(next(ids), org_list)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # we just call update on the group so update is called
    # an every sprite in the group
    org_list.update()

    screen.fill(colors['white'])

    # same for drawing: just call draw on the group
    org_list.draw(screen)

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Again, specifically, I'm looking to pass on width and height when there are parents with width and height, but in the initial genesis spawn when there have been no parents, I want those values to have been randomly generated.

Comment: You pass `width` and `height` in `__init__` and then set `self.width` and `self.height` with them if they aren't empty and, if they are, they are randomized. So everything seems to be correct, what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti seems to be right, you can create the first on the line with the randomized set by the init , and then the offpring can be another instance the same class Organism, just set the argument of width and height from parents as parent.width , parent.height

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the constructor of the class `organism` has a `width` and a `height` argument and these then set the attributes `self.width` and `self.height` with them if they are not empty (`None`) and if they are, they are set by random values:

> ```py
> class Organism(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
>
>    def __init__(self, id, org_list, width, height, color = None):
>        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, org_list)
>
>        self.width = width or random.randrange(20,60)
>        self.height = height or random.randrange(20,60)
>
>        # [...]
> ```

Therefore, if you want random values, you must pass `None` to these arguments:

```py
for _ in range(15):
    Organism(next(ids), org_list, None, None)
```

Alternatively, you can pass concrete values, for example, the width and height of the parent:

```py
class Organism(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        # [...]

        if collided and not collided.id in self.collisions and collided.age > 200 and len(self.org_list) < 100:
            # [...]

            Organism(next(ids), self.org_list, self.width, self.height, list(map(int, color)))
```